# How to make a specific colour in an image transparent in Android studio?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin, imageview

I'm using an image that has the letters "LYIT" and a white background. I want to make the white background transparent so only the letters are visible.

I've tried `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` but it only changes a small portion of the image [Logo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7bxj.png).

`app:tint="@color/colorWhite"` doesn't work either.

Is there a way I can target the white portion of the image and make it transparent?

Also, I'm writing my classes in Kotlin.

Thanks

Comment: Maybe better idea is create SVG version without background?)

Comment: Using `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` on an ImageView will only replace the background of the View containing your picture. If your picture is not transparent, it'll not automatically crop the letters.

The best way is to give a transparent SVG (or PNG) resource to your ImageView.

Comment: @KilianP. But PNG loss quality on different devices) So best for that situation is SVG

Comment: @Syorito Hatsuki Sure, SVG is a must-use ! But in his case we don't know if the "logo" is available in SVG (maybe he only has a PNG available) and it's an useful information that indicates he can use PNG in the worst case if needed.

Comment: @KilianP. That's true) If my customer send me PNG I ask double price for use it in project :D Then all starting create correct files)

Comment: @SyoritoHatsuki how would I make an SVG version?

Comment: @cWizzle As best, u need to redraw it in Inkspace, Krita, GIMP or Adobe Illustration or as bad method u can remove white background in paint, save as PNG and convert online to SVG, but if u use convector is not help u to save quality. Read about Vector and Raster graphics.

Comment: @SyoritoHatsuki I just tried an online converter and the new file gives me an error. I'll check out your recommendations. Thanks very much!

Comment: Inkspace would be the best option, the xml format that uses Android Studio for svg is not the standard one, Inkspace is kinda similar, i've had no luck creating svg with other software

Answer (score -1):

I found this answer at another question,
you can write the following code in the backend

```
val image = findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.*write the id of the image here*)
image.background.alpha = 0 //the value of alpha's range is [0,255], 0is transperent and 255 is quite opaque
```